# Sending datapoints to two charts every second

Tags: javascript

I want to send field data every second to a web page that contains two charts. The two charts are defined below and work ok with fixed data. For dynamic data I send the single x and two y data points to the addData function which looks like:

```
      function addData(label, data0, data1)
      {
         myChart0.data.labels.push(label);
         myChart0.data.datasets.data.push(data0);
         myChart1.data.labels.push(label); 
         myChart1.data.datasets.data.push(data1);

         myChart0.update();        
         myChart1.update();        
      }
```

The code fails for the line:

`myChart0.data.datasets.data.push(data0);`
The error message from the browser is:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push').

Chart code:

```
      var ctx0 = document.getElementById('myChart0').getContext('2d');
      const plotData0 = {
         labels: [],
         datasets: 
            [{
               data: [],
               label: "WEIGHT",
               borderColor: 'red',
               borderWidth: 2,
               tension: 0,
               fill: false
            }],
         };
               
      var myChart0 = new Chart(ctx0, {
         type: 'line',
         data: plotData0,
            options: 
            {
               scales: 
               {
                  yAxes: 
                  [{
                     type: 'linear',
                     position: 'left',
                  }]
               },
            elements: 
            {
               point: 
               {
                  radius: 0,
               }
            },
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
         }
      })

      var ctx1 = document.getElementById('myChart1').getContext('2d');
      const plotData1 = {
         labels: [],
         datasets: 
            [{
               data: [],
               label: "SENSOR-1",
               borderColor: 'blue',
               borderWidth: 2,
               tension: 0,
               fill: false
            }],
         };
         
      var myChart1 = new Chart(ctx1, {
         type: 'line',
         data: plotData1,
            options: 
            {
               scales: 
               {
                  yAxes: 
                  [{
                     type: 'linear',
                     position: 'left',
                  }]
               },
            elements: 
            {
               point: 
               {
                  radius: 0,
               }
            },
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
         }
      })
```

I have tried various syntax changes but I guess the problem is I don't understand how the data is being transferred from the addData function into the chart data[] arrays.

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The value for your `datasets` property is wrapped in square brackets, which makes it an array.  Inside the array there is one object (an object is wrapped in curly braces). To access the object in the array, you can use array index syntax, which uses an array index inside square brackets. You might write the `addData` function like this:

```
function addData(label, data0, data1)
  {
     myChart0.data.labels.push(label);
     myChart0.data.datasets[0].data.push(data0);
     myChart1.data.labels.push(label); 
     myChart1.data.datasets[0].data.push(data1);

     myChart0.update();        
     myChart1.update();        
  }
```

Alternatively, you could leave the `addData` function as is and instead remove the square brackets that are wrapping the value for the `datasets` property:

```
const plotData0 = {
     labels: [],
     datasets: 
        {
           data: [],
           label: "WEIGHT",
           borderColor: 'red',
           borderWidth: 2,
           tension: 0,
           fill: false
        },
     };




const plotData1 = {
     labels: [],
     datasets: 
        {
           data: [],
           label: "SENSOR-1",
           borderColor: 'blue',
           borderWidth: 2,
           tension: 0,
           fill: false
        },
     };
```

Comment: Would you believe I saw that moments after posting the question! That fixed the error and although everything appears to work such as the x axis labelling, the data is not being plotted, and neither does the y axis reflect the y value range as the new data is posted.  More troubleshooting required.